# where am i going wrong with my jquery form

Tags: jquery, forms

The form will send to the php file but I am having trouble getting the error messages to show when it is incorrectly filled out. Can you spot any basic errors I might be missing? I am new to JQuery and I can't use a plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var username = $('#username').val();
   var email = $('#email').val();


  function submitDetailsForm()
  {
  if (username == '') {
     $('#usernameError').html('Please insert your username!');
    }
    else {
     return true;
     }

  if (email == '') {
     $('#emailError').html('Please enter an email!');
    }
    else {
     return true;
     }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: if you add some of the html to your code, I'd be able to help you more

Comment: please show some html, just to make sure id "usernameError" and emailError display is not "none" and please set username and email variable in your function.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of errors, but you can get the idea from this code.

```
$('#formId').submit(function(){
    var hasErrors = false; 
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();

    if (username == '') {
        $('#usernameError').html('Please insert your username!');
        hasErrors = true; //username is empty, lets set our variable to true
    }

    if (email == '') {
        $('#emailError').html('Please enter an email!');
        hasErrors = true; //email is empty, lets set our variable to true
    }

    if(!hasErrors){ //if the variable was false that means there was no error
        $("#usernameError,#emailError").html('');//Clear error message when form is valid
        return true; //continue with the form submission
    } else { //else if it is true, that means we have an error
        return false; //prevent the form submission
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ct588wdb/)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Did the trick to solve the problem I was having. If I wanted to add a few rules to each one, like has to be letters for username where do i squeeze that in?

Answer (score -1):

Compare Strings by `===`, not only `==`

You should check username and email for `undefined`, too